# Highlight in red on a missing field or clickaway

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to highlight a textbox in red when its empty on a submit and then bring it back to black when the user enters text and clicks away.  This has no effect at all.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 <style>
  :required {
    border-color: #FF0000;
  }
</style>

 $(document).ready(function ()
  {
  var email = $('#Email').val();

  if (!email || email === "") {
   document.getElementsByClassName("Email").className = document.getElementsByClassName("Email").className + " 
  required"; 
  }
  else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("Email").style.border = "1px solid black";
   }
            

  }

@using (Html.BeginForm(...)
{
   <div class="form-group row Email"  id="Email">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { placeholder = "Enter your email", @class = "form- 
  input" })
  </div>
 

 <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" class="form-input"/>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the element by the id Email but your div does not have the "Email" id, it is a class.

Instead of:

```
let element = document.getElementById("Email")
```

you could use this:

```
let element = document.getElementsByClassName("Email")[0]
```

Also you could add an id attribute to your div and set it to "Email"

```
<div class="form-group row Email" id="Email">
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { 
      placeholder = "Enter your email", 
      @class = "form-input"
   })
</div>
```

Comment: Made those changes and edited the post.  No change in results though.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("Email") returns a array of elements, probably your element is in the first position. You can access it like this:

var element = document.getElementsByClassName("Email")[0]